# How to execute an if statement in ManyToMany Field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to check if voter already exists in database and execute a different command id the voter exists or not but my if statement returns False if there is a match in the database.

My views is:

```
def vote(request, position_id, voting_id):
    voter = Voter.objects.filter(pk=voting_id)
    print(voter)
    position = get_object_or_404(Position, pk=position_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = position.candidate_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Candidate.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'landing/detail.html', {
            'position': position,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a Choice."
        })
    else:
        print(selected_choice.voted_by.all())
        if voter in selected_choice.voted_by.all():
            print("THIS DOES")
        else:
            print("THIS DOESN'T")
        # selected_choice.votes += 1
        # selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results', args=(position.id,)))
```

When I run this, I have some print statements and it prints;

```
<QuerySet [<Voter: BIS/2019/12345>]>
<QuerySet [<Voter: BIT/2020/54321>, <Voter: BIT/2019/12345>, <Voter: BIT/2018/12345>, <Voter:  BIS/2020/54321>, <Voter: BIS/2019/12345>]>
THIS DOESN'T
```

I was hoping it will print 'THIS DOES' since the voter is in the selected_choice.

What might I be doing wrong

Comment: Your voter is not a single `Voter` object, but a *QuerySet* (collection) of `Voter`s, you should work with `voter =Voter.objects.get(pk=voting_id)`, or even better with `get_olbject_or_404(...)`.

Comment: The above plus best to check by using `if selected_choice.voted_by.filter(pk=voter.pk).exists():`

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem, It has worked